# Add servlet filter to a Grails app dynamically

Tags: java, servlets, grails, runtime, servlet-filters

I have a scenario where, if a user gives my Grails app a certain type of input, I want to dynamically add a `javax.servlet.Filter` impl (`MyCustomerFilter`) so that all subsequent requests to the server get passed through this filter.

In other words, when the Grails app starts up, `MyCustomFilter` is not activated and is not in the filter chain. But when the user does something (let's say makes an AJAX call back to a server-side controller) I want to add `MyCustomFilter` to the filter chain and activate it (for all future/subsequent requests).

Is this possible? If so, how? If not, why?

Comment: Why not have it already added into the chain but allow the actual filtering to be toggled runtime within the filter itself?

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaMoore (+1) - I guess I'mm not quite following you. Are you saying that you can activate/deactivate filters on the chain (programmatically). If so, how could I specify `MyCustomFilter` to be on the chain - but *deactivated* at startup, and then, how could I programmatically activate it at a later time?

Comment: See Graeme's answer, it's what I was describing in my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't dynamically add a filter, you can however add filter that either wraps the request or just passes it along the filter chain depending on user input